# Reporting on Dynamic content used in an email part of a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, journeybuilder, email-studio

I am currently planning on building a Journey with emails that have dynamic content.

The dynamic content is used for having 12 language emails versions and the 2 dynamic emails will be sent as part of a Journey.

How can I report on the emails with dynamic content in a Journey: `opens`, `clicks`?

Answer (score 2):

For Clicks, you can use Impression Region Tracking; You have to get that enabled by support and then can set regions in your email which show up in a special report.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_impression_tracking.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

---

For "dynamic Opens" aka "who saw what", you should consider a sendlog, also enabled via support:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm

Create a SendLog Data Extension.

In each dynamic part of the email that not everyone will see, set an AMPScript variable.
For starters, let's assume there is only one block.

in the content of each dynamic block variant, one AMPScript line should be found, e.g.:

```
%%[
SET @blockdisplayed = "variant1" 
]%%
```

,

```
%%[
SET @blockdisplayed = "variant2" 
]%%
```

and so forth.

Add an extra field to the sendlog data extension which mirrors the variable name:

blockdisplayed, text, 50

Upon send, this automatically fills with the eponymous AMPScript variable value at send time.

Preliminary result: you now have a DE (the send log) in which every sent email is tracked with subscriberID (yes, not subscriberKey), jobid, batchid, listid PLUS the variable value, so you know which person received what block at send time.

To make this work for your Journey Emails, make sure the box "retain send log data" in the Send email activity is checked to follow this plan.

With this, you should know what content was SENT through your journeys.
In order to know what content was OPENED, you need to work with SQL Queries on the data views, in conjunction with your Sendlog.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5

Note that journey sends are handled differently in data views than normal sends.
this is a good starting point, these are the sends of the last 24 hours:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours.htm&type=5

Join something like the above with the _job and _open data views, and your sendlog.
Ensure that the joins are on *jobid,listid and batchid*, as Journey Builder uses one JobId consistently unless the Journey Version changes. i.e. JobID is not unique for each send.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Enable Send Logging, and ensure the Field Names in the Data Extension you are using to target the mailing are mapped in Send Logging.

You will also indicate the name of the Send Log Data Extension. E.g. SendLog

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm

E.g. Language

At the time of send, a record will be stored in your send log with the following important information:

- JobID `The job ID number for the email send`
- SubID `The subscriber ID for the affected subscriber. This number represents the unique ID for each subscriber record.`
- Language `Field Name from Data Extension. This will capture the value at time of send. E.g. English, Spanish, etc.`

Once the mailing is complete, you can use the following SQL in Automation Studio to export data that will contain the Opens / Clicks for each user and each language.

```
SELECT sendlog.JobID
      ,sendlog.Language
      ,(
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM _Open AS o WITH (NOLOCK)
           WHERE sendlog.SubID = o.SubID
             AND sendlog.JobID = o.JobID
      ) AS [Opens]
      ,(
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM _Click AS c WITH (NOLOCK)
           WHERE sendlog.SubID = c.SubID
             AND sendlog.JobID = c.JobID
      ) AS [Clicks]
FROM [SendLog] AS sendlog WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE JobID = {JobID}
GROUP BY sendlog.JobID
        ,sendlog.Language
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!